# Is a simple group a simple semigroup?

Tags: group-theory

A semigroup is called simple if it does not have non-trivial ideals. Is a simple group a simple semigroup? Thank you very much.

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem? Do you know any examples of ideals in groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Theorem: Let $S$ be a semigroup. Then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> i. S is both left simple and right simple.
>
> ii. S is a group

This theorem shows us that every group is both left simple and right simple and so it is simple, however; the notion of simplicity in semigroups is different from the meaning of simplicity in group theory,i.e, not having a non-trivial normal subgroups.

Comment: Hi dear Babak. safar be kheir va ziarat ghabool. Happy Eid. khoobin ishalla?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: Mamnunam Mahdi jan. Are khub bud-o emam ro ziyarat kardam. Jaye shoma khali. Adam unja reset mishe bara ye dore dg ta sale baad. Unja zehnam az hamechi khali bud joz tawajoh be uuu. :-)

Comment: Kheili Mamnoon. Khosh be haletoon. Man kheili vaghte naraftam oonja.

Answer (score 1):

Try to prove that every group is a simple semigroup.